# Microk8s high cpu usage

Tags: 22.04, kubernetes, microk8s

I recently installed microk8s on a Ubuntu 22.04 server (running on VirtualBox 7, windows 10 as host). The VM has 6 cores and 32gb of ram, so it has plenty of resources.

Microk8s is installed via snap from channel 1.27/stable.

I'm not running any pods and k8s is using ~20% of the system. I've read that [disabling ha on a single host deployment](https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/1567) made the situation a lot better, which I've done, but is 20% cpu usage on idle normal for microk8s?

For example, this is the output from `sar`

```
$ sar 5
Linux 5.15.0-73-generic (********)   14/06/23        _x86_64_        (6 CPU)

16:21:56        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
16:22:01        all      1.08      0.00     17.31      0.56      0.00     81.05
16:22:06        all      1.30      0.00     15.57      0.59      0.00     82.54
16:22:11        all      1.29      0.00     29.30      0.47      0.00     68.94
16:22:16        all      1.28      0.00     17.21      0.52      0.00     80.99
16:22:21        all      1.30      0.00     15.12      0.51      0.00     83.07
16:22:26        all      0.94      0.00     15.85      0.31      0.00     82.90
16:22:31        all      1.20      0.00     19.19      0.28      0.00     79.33
16:22:36        all      1.11      0.00     16.27      0.48      0.00     82.14
```

From top I can see that the 2 main processes using CPU are `kubelite` and `etcd`. If I stop microk8s the usage drops under 1% of cpu.

I'm not a k8s expert, but this doesn't seem right. Any tips?

Comment: I found a few similar questions on the microk8s github repo and it looks like this is normal. I dropped microk8s, installed K3s and the CPU utilisation halved.